# What is the concept of male and female in Hinduism?

Tags: vedas, sex, sankhya, gender

Male and female gender exists not only in humans (and animals) but almost everything.
Even devtas (like Varun, Indra etc) and "inanimate" objects (eg-river) have gender.
What is the basic concept of gender in Hinduism ?